# Openlayers with custom Renderer, vertexShader & fragmentShader

Tags: glsl, shader, webgl, openlayers, openlayers-7

I am looking to render some output to an openlayers map using the vertexShader & fragmentShader from the WebGL options. The long term goal is something like the effect at [windy.com](https://www.windy.com).

I have created a CustomWebGLPointsLayer (extending ol/layer/WebGLPoints) & specified some simple shaders to control for position & color. With my CustomWebGLPointsLayer, data points are being placed in the center of the map resulting in a triangle (top left, top right, center) on the map. This triangle also ignores the color(s) I am attempting to set.

Questions are:

- How can I get these points rendered appropriately?
- How can I get the dynamic color to work correctly?

Repo is [here](https://github.com/Tomcariello/ol-animated_wind_vectors) if you want to play with the code.

CustomWebGLPointsLayer instantiation:

```
class CustomWebGLPointsLayer extends WebGLPointsLayer {
  createRenderer() {
    return new WebGLPointsLayerRenderer(this, { 
      // "attributes" are passed into the shaders
      attributes: [
        {
          name: 'a_coords',
          callback: function(feature) {
            // Array of XY positions per feature to pass to the vertexShader.
            const coordinatesArr = [ 
              feature.values_[0],
              feature.values_[1],
            ];
            return coordinatesArr;
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'a_color',
          callback: function(feature) {
            // Create an array of some colors & select one at random
            const colorsArr = {
              "red":   `[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]`,
              "green": `[0.0, 1.0, 0.0]`,
              "blue":  `[0.0, 0.0, 1.0]`,
            };

            const obj = Object.keys(colorsArr);
            const randomColor = obj[Math.floor(Math.random() * obj.length)];
            const vec3_color = colorsArr[randomColor];

            return vec3_color;
          }
        }
      ],
      vertexShader: 
      `
      // Specify the precision level to use with floats in this shader.
      precision mediump float;

      // Declare attributes; these values are passed into GLSL from JavaScript
      attribute vec2 a_coords;
      attribute vec3 a_color;

      // Declare varyings; these values will be passed along to the fragmentShader
      varying vec3 v_color;

      void main() {
        gl_Position = vec4(a_coords, 0.0, 0.0); // Set the position
        v_color = vec3(a_color); // set the value of v_color <-- This doesn't work?
      }
      `,
      // This should paint all fragments the value of v_color
      fragmentShader: `
      precision mediump float;

      // Declare varyings; these values have been passed along from the vertexShader
      varying vec3 v_color;

      void main() {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(v_color, 0.5); // Set the color dynamically - DOESN'T WORK
        // gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5); // pink; WORKS!
        // gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 0.5); // red; WORKS! (testing ints, not floats)
      }
      `
    })
  }
};
```

And the map

```
const map = new Map({
      layers: [
        new Tile({ source: new OSM() }),
        // new WebGLPointsLayer({ // Use this if you want to see the points rendered statically
        new CustomWebGLPointsLayer({
          source: new VectorSource({ features: featuresArr }),
          style: {
            symbol: {
              symbolType: "triangle",
              size: 16,
              color: "red",
              rotation: ["*", ["get", "deg"], Math.PI / 180],
              rotateWithView: true,
            },
          },
        }),
      ],
      target: "map",
      view: new View({center: [0, 0],zoom: 0,}),
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the color passing into the shaders now, which effectively answers this question (which, if phrased better, was "How can I pass unique values per feature to the shaders?). Repo is updated if you want to play with it.

Here is my custom layer. You can see that I separated the RGB values into distinct attributes. featureColorRed, featureColorBlue & featureColorGreen are all set as features during data processing. Each is a FLOAT which appears to be a requirement of passing data into the shaders(?).

```
// A custom renderer intended to draw GLSL output to a layer
class CustomWebGLPointsLayer extends WebGLPointsLayer {
  createRenderer() {
    return new WebGLPointsLayerRenderer(this, { 
      attributes: [
        {
          name: 'featureColorRed',
          callback: function(feature) {
            const color = feature.values_.featureColorRed;
            return color;
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'featureColorGreen',
          callback: function(feature) {
            const color = feature.values_.featureColorGreen;
            return color;
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'featureColorBlue',
          callback: function(feature) {
            const color = feature.values_.featureColorBlue;
            return color;
          }
        },
      ],

      vertexShader: 
      `
      attribute vec2 a_coordinates;
      attribute float a_featureColorRed;
      varying vec4 v_featureColor;

      attribute float a_featureColorGreen;
      varying vec4 v_featureColorGreen;

      attribute float a_featureColorBlue;
      varying vec4 v_featureColorBlue;

      void main() {
        v_featureColor = vec4(a_featureColorRed, a_featureColorGreen, a_featureColorBlue, 1.0);
        gl_Position = vec4(a_coordinates, 0.0, 1.0);
      }`,

      fragmentShader: `
      precision mediump float;

      varying vec4 v_featureColor;

      void main() {
        gl_FragColor = v_featureColor;
      }
      `
    })
  }
};
```

Then creating my custom layer. featuresArr is the data that has been processed. IDK why I need to include "symbolType" here but without this style object OL fails to load.

```
const customGLSLLayer = new CustomWebGLPointsLayer({
  source: new VectorSource({ features: featuresArr }),
  style: {
    symbol: {
      symbolType: "square",
    },
  },
  zIndex: 10,
});
```

And finally, the map (which is pretty standard).

```
const map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new Tile({ 
      source: new OSM(), 
      zIndex: 1, 
    }),
    customGLSLLayer
  ],
  target: "map",
  view: new View({center: [0, 0],zoom: 0,}),
});
```